# Ruby - Finding primes under 100?

Tags: ruby, methods, primes

I'd like to write a code that prints out all primes under 100. Here is the code I have so far

```
class Numbers

  def is_a_prime?(int)
    x = 2
    while x < int/2
      if int % x == 0
        return false
      else
        return true
      end
    end
  end

  def primes_under_100
    x = 2
    while x < 100
      print x if is_a_prime?(x) # calling the method I defined above
      x+= 1
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately when I call the method using primes_under_100 I get

```
undefined local variable or method 'primes_under_100' for main:Object
```

I'd like to know where I went wrong. None of my methods are private. Help is appreciated.

Comment: how are you calling this? `Numbers.new.primes_under_100`?

Comment: Your code will break when calling `Numbers.new.primes_under_100` because you're attempting to call `is_a_prime?` on a `Fixnum` not a `Numbers` object on the line `print x if x.is_a_prime? # calling the method I defined above`

Comment: I called using primes_under_100

Comment: Just for reference, Ruby also has a [Prime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2//libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html) class which can be used to generate / check for prime numbers. Be sure to first `require 'prime'`.

Comment: also, this method has to be called on FixNum, because prime numbers are positive integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your code to work you will need to make the following modifications

```
class Numbers

  def is_a_prime?(int)
    x = 2
    while x < int/2
      if int % x == 0
        return false
      else
        return true
      end
    end
  end

  def primes_under_100
    x = 2
    while x < 100
      # Notice you're calling is_a_prime? on the instance of the Numbers object 
      # and sending x as an argument. Not calling is_a_prime? on the 'x'
      print x if is_a_prime?(x) 
      x+= 1
    end
  end
end
```

Then call `Numbers.new.primes_under_100`

Comment: I understand that code is instantiating a new object through the Numbers class. But could you please explain why I need to create a new object to call a function?

Comment: @user3662249 Because you wrote your code as instance methods. They only can be called on an instance of the Numbers class, not the class itself.

Comment: Should you be incrementing x in is_a_prime?() ?

Answer (score 2):

An other way to do this is extend Fixnum. Whit this you should be able to call it on int values.

this should be something like this

```
class Fixnum
  def is_a_prime?
    (2..(self/2)).each do |x|
      if self % x == 0
        return false
      end
    end
    return true
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for the idea of patching Fixnum, which is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: I think patching around in core classes is the ruby way to do things :D

Comment: Totally! Ok, it's probably a bad/terrible plan for serious projects that might actually expect those core classes to work the way they were written, but for a simple script, it can be fine (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling it? They are public methods of the `Number` class, so in order to call them, you need to instantiate an object of the `Number` class:

```
number = Numbers.new
primes = number.primes_under_100
```

Also, as the comment from Leo Correa in my answer stated, the method `is_a_prime?` can't be called like that, you should use:

```
print x if is_a_prime?(x)
```

Comment: His class is called `Numbers` not `Number`. Also, his code will break because he's attempting to call `is_a_prime?(int)` on a `Fixnum` instance not a `Numbers`

Comment: I learned that you call a method without parameters simply by stating that method's name. If it has parameters you call the method with arguments inside parentheses. To call it, I simply typed the method name, 'primes_under_100'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Ruby include this method to Prime, but if you are using 2.2 and higher you can do it like this.

Add this to top of the file

```rb
require 'prime'
```

And method for showing primes under specific number.

```rb
Prime.each(100) do |prime|
  p prime  #=> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...., 97
end
```

[Here is the reference](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Prime.html)